# How to make a middle step between 2 execute sql task in ssis package

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have a package that looks like this:

[image]

When I add a constrain between the for loop and the SQL Task on the left side, it will stop the package at the execute sql task on the middle.

Like this:

[image]

How to make this work? I tried lots of ways but nothing is working.

Comment: You have two branches coming out of Execute SQL Task. There is a mutually exclusive condition such that either `SQL Task - Set ExecutionLock` fires or `For Loop Container` runs, yes?

Answer (score 1):

Set one of the constraints to '**Logical OR**'. 
You have multiple constraints leading to 'Sql task - Set ExecutionLock'. If you left the constraint with the default value of '**Logical AND**', both paths would have to evaluate to true in order for this task to execute.

[image]

[image]